# Youtube API with AFNetworking failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to use the Youtube API to pull in all the videos from a particular channel. I set up the project in Google Developers Console and got an API browser key. I enabled YouTube Data API v3 and for safe measure, I enabled YouTube Analytics API.

I do not know what I am getting this error. Can anyone help me. This is my console output.

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
 {
  "domain": "usageLimits",
  "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
  "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
  "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
 }
],
"code": 403,
"message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add any bundle id's to "Edit allowed iOS apps..." in your API Access panel?  If you did, remove them all.  **iOS apps:** should now say "Any app allowed".  This fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am told that this is fixed by simply removing all Ip's from the edit allowed IP's option. This makes it so that **it is less secure**, but it will accept all IP's after that.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSbTL.jpg]